# Type projection example from "Scala in Action" (chapter 8)

Tags: scala, types

could anyone help me with below code bits from the book?

```
trait Mapper[F[_]] {
  def fmap[A, B](xs: F[A], f: A => B): F[B]   
}

def VectorMapper = new Mapper[Vector] {
  def fmap[A, B](xs: Vector[A], f: A => B): Vector[B] = xs map f 
}
```

That was simple: trait definition using higher-kinded type `F[_]` for usage with any "container-like" types, then a concrete mapper for `Vector`.

Then goes a tricky part. Mapper for `Either`.
I understand `{type E[A] = Either[X, A]}` just as a block of code, and `({type E[A] = Either[X, A]})#E` as a projection that takes that type alias `E` out of the anonymous block of code and by that author "hides" the presence of `X` for the `Mapper` trait because trait operates on single type parameter "container types" only - and we are interested in `A`, i.e. `Right`.

```
def EitherMapper[X] = new Mapper[({type E[A] = Either[X, A]})#E ] {
    def fmap[A, B](r: Either[X, A], f: A => B): Either[X, B] = r match {
        case Left(a) => Left(a)
        case Right(a) => Right(f(a))
    }     
}
```

**Question:**
Why do we need `X` in the `def EitherMapper[X] =` part?

Thanks for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either is dependent on two types, for instance `Either[Int, String]`

`EitherMapper` is a type constructor that is dependent just on one type, so when you have a `EitherMapper[Int]`, you are dealing with a `Either[Int, A]`, and `A` is resolved into the Mapper part, this way you can have any `A=>B` function, because the first type of `Either` is already present for the Mapper and you return a `Either[X, B]`.

Indeed the type E[A] is equivalent to Either[X, A], you have just one degree of freedom regarding to types!

```
val right: Either[Boolean, String] = Right("test")
val left: Either[Boolean, String] = Left(false)

println(EitherMapper.fmap(right, (s: String) => s.length))
> Right(4)
println(EitherMapper.fmap(left, (s: String) => s.length))
> Left(false)
```

In this case the type is `EitherMapper[Boolean]` and the type of fmap is `fmap[String, Integer]`, it accepts `Either[Boolean, String]` and return `Either[Boolean, Integer]`.

As you can see the type of fmap doesn't say anything on the `X` part of the `Either[X, A]` type so in the end you could use the  `(s: String) => s.length)` function for others `EitherMapper[X]` types, in simple words the "left" part of the either type can be anything you want, and it's the "X" part of the type construction.

Hope it's clearer now!

Comment: Vincenzo, hi. Could you kindly illustrate the usage of the `EitherMapper`, may be this would make it clearer? I'm asking this, because, say, for `VectorMapper` it is simple like `val v = VectorMapper.fmap(someVectorOfInts, _ => _ * 2)`

Comment: Yes, just wait a little 'cause I need to take my laptop where I've installed Scala